# Why there occurs an error while I tried to install packages using npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

I am working in react js . While installing packages I got the following error as shown in the image. I tried many ways but nothing becomes right. How can I solve this issue?[IMAGE OF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywi3U.png)

Answer (score 0):

you havn't installed python yet

### So install python !

Still problem persist then try

```sh
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: how to install python?